# How to cut a rounded area at a certain border?

Tags: flutter

How to cut a rounded area at a [image]certain border?

Only Canvas or ClipPath?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ClipRRect`.You can give the border radius and its value.
It is like this...

```
ClipRRect(
 borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
 topLeft: Radius.circular(15.0),
 topRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
 bottomRight: Radius.circular(15.0),
 ),
child: Align(
 alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
 heightFactor: 0.5,
 widthFactor: 0.5,
 child:Image.network("https://..."),
 ),
)
```

Comment: No, I need to cut out a part of the widget.